# Reference update in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, copy-constructor

I have a simple question regarding reference update in c++. Consider below C++ code:

```
class A
{
    int b;

    public:
    int& setb();
    int getb();
    A();
    A &operator= (const A &t)
    {
        cout<<"Assignment called"<<endl;
    }
    A(int i):b(i) {
        cout<<"Copy contructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

int A::getb()
{
    cout<<this->b<<endl;
}

int& A::setb()
{
    return b;
}

A::A()
{
    cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout<<"About to set reference"<<endl;
    a.setb()=5;
    a.getb();

    return 0;
}
```

When I update `b` via reference how is the value copied? Is there any default copy constructor which is being called ?

Comment: A reference doesn't make a copy.

Comment: A reference is essentially a hidden pointer.

Comment: but in this case If I am updating a private member of class it should be updated by some object of class right?

Comment: You cause undefined behaviour by not having a return statement in `operator=`

Comment: @M.M that's not really relevant to the question.  People too often nitpick the testcases.

Comment: @MayankJain The member function is allowed to access the private member. And by returning a reference, it makes it accessible to any other function.

Comment: Let me change my question a bit.. Let's say I have another member of same class int c and I want to update c when b gets updated. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @M.M - For above code assignment called is not printed at all.. Means the operator is not getting called ever.

Comment: Including `c = 5;` inside `setb` is the closest you can do in this structure

Comment: Isn't your copy constructor wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to understand this, at least for me, is to imagine that you work with pointers, not references:

```
int* A::setb()
{
    return &b;
}
```

Now if you do this:

```
*(a.setb())=5;
```

It becomes clear what happens. References do exactly the same thing, but without all that `*&` mumbo-jumbo. Your assignment/copy constructors have nothing to do with this whatsoever. Now, if your field wasn't `int`, but of some custom type, then the assignment operator of *that* type would be called. You could do whatever you want to in that assignment.

One interesting trick is that your `setb` may return a “smart reference” type that actually updates `b`, but may do something more:

```
class TwoIntsRef {
public:
    TwoIntsRef(int &a, int &b) :
        a(a),
        b(b)
    {}
    TwoIntsRef& operator=(int c)
    {
        cout << "TwoIntsRef Assignment called" << endl;
        a = c;
        b = c;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int &a;
    int &b;
};
```

And then you do this:

```
TwoIntsRef A::setb()
{
    return TwoIntsRef(b, c);
}
```

And this:

```
a.setb() = 5;
```

Now it sets both `b` and `c`.

This is actually a very useful trick that may do a lot of things. In one of my projects I had to port legacy code that relied heavily on Big Endian byte order. To make it work on Little Endian hardware I had to replace all memory access with smart references that would swap bytes automatically. Not a very efficient way, but the only one that would work in that particular project.

Answer (score 1):

No, when you update b via reference, no copy constructor whether implicit or explicitly defined will be called.

A Copy constructor is called when while defining (memory is not allocated yet) , you are assigning value to the object
ex

`A obj = a;`

Assignment operator will be called, when the object is already defined (memory already allocated) and you want to change the fields of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Through your code, I see that you use the default copy constructor of C++ compiler. It will use copy constructor of each non-static member of your class. Note that the generated constructor in your case will look likes:

```
A(const &A other) 
:   b(other.b) 
{}
```

and it will be called int these cases:

```
A a;
...
A b = a;
...
A c(a);
```

In other words, the copy constructor will be called when your construct new object from other object in same class. Your constructor from int is not a copy constructor.

Second, why you set b private while everybody can modified it via your setb()? 
I think a better way to implement your setb() is:

```
void A::setb(const int& val) {
    b = val;
}
```